# Is it possible to inject parameters into protected constructors using Unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container, constructor-injection

I can do this in Castle Windsor:

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    protected AbstractFactory(Foo constructorParm)
    {
        // Do something with parameter...
    }
}

public class DescendentFactory : AbstractFactory
{
    public DescendentFactory(Foo constructorParm) : base(constructorParm)
    {
    }
}

// The container is configured via XML, the service AbstractFactory and the
// type DescendentFactory
container.Resolve<AbstractFactory>("DescendentFactoryId", new { constructorParm = injectedValue });
```

Is this possible in Unity?  I've tried doing it but it complains that it can't find the constructor.  It seems I can only inject via the sub-type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only inject via the sub-type. It needs a public constructor.